# VBA array of class objects inside object returns out of stack space error

Tags: arrays, vba, class

I am trying to illustrate the concept of using an array inside the Class Bookstore to store many book objects with the following code. I do not wish to use a collection for this task, because later on I like really to be able to access the Book(i), and do code depending on the i position within the array size.
A little research in stackoverflow indicates that I should use ReDim statement, but did not show where and how exactly.

Class Bookstore:

```
Private pBooks As Variant ' it will hold an array of object book
Public Property Get Books() As Variant:  Books = pBooks:  End Property
Public Property Let Books(v As Variant): Books = v:       End Property
```

Class Book:

```
Private pName As String
Public Property Get Name() As String:     Name = pName:   End Property
Public Property Let Name(s As String):   pName = s:       End Property
```

Testing Code:

```
Sub TestBookstore()

Dim bookArray(1 To 2) As Book, i As Long
For i = 1 To 2
 Set bookArray(i) = New Book
 bookArray(i).Name = "book called " & i
Next i

 Dim BKStore As Bookstore: Set BKStore = New Bookstore
   BKStore.Books = bookArray       ' ERROR HERE: out of stack space

 For i = LBound(BKStore.Books) To UBound(BKStore.Books)
   Debug.Print BKStore.Books(i).Name
 Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss a p in your code. YOu have to refer to your class internal variable.

```
Public Property Let Books(v As Variant): pBooks = v:       End Property
```

I also prefer to use more space in such a case. This could make such errors more obvious

```
Public Property Let Books(v As Variant)
    pBooks = v
End Property
```

Comment: Thanks Storax. As for me, I prefer somehow to list similar stuff under each other. Now VBA does not allow to format spacing at my will, but in MQL (like C) I achieved good performance of clarity and errors should show up easily that way.

Comment: FIne with me, as I said I prefer to use more lines. Matter of taste ...